# Exit only if $return -eq 'exit' always exits

Tags: powershell

I have a main script that calls several sub scripts that may run into an error. When they do, they exit nicely but so should the main script. Therefore, I implemented variations on the following statement in several locations of the sub scripts:

```
$testSomething = Test-Path $something
if (-not $testSomething) {
    write-host 'error message'
    return 'exit'
    exit
}
```

The main script calls the sub scripts thusly:

```
$return = .\subScript.ps1 parameter1 etc.
```

After which I figured this:

```
if ($return -eq 'exit') {
    Read-Host -Prompt 'Press Enter to exit'
    exit
}
```

However, the main script always exits regardless if the sub script encounters an error or not. I triple checked that it doesn't go into any of the if statements that return the value 'exit' and yet it exits. What am I overlooking?

Edit:
Per request, below is the main script in its entirety (only the first two sub scripts can generate a show stopping error). This version is after a fruitless attempt to get the above to work by changing the if statements in the sub scripts to the following, which results in the script never exiting:

```
$testSomething = Test-Path $something
if (-not $testSomething) {
    $result = $null
    return $result
    exit
}
```

Main script:

```
param (
    [parameter(mandatory)] [string] $versie,
    [parameter()] [string] $versieSoort,
    [parameter()] [string] $dataSet,
    [parameter()] [string] $rollBack,
    [parameter()] [switch] $updateDataOnly,
    [parameter()] [string] $scriptMapLokaal
)

if (!$dataSet) {
    $dataSet = 'standaard'
}
if (!$scriptMapLokaal) {
    $scriptMapLokaal = 'C:\UpdateScript'
}

$stopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

$buildDrop = '\\somewhere'
$dataPadNetwerk = '\\somewhereElse'

Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

$return = .\Subscripts\1_checkVoorwaarden.ps1 -versie $versie -versieSoort $versieSoort -dataSet $dataSet -rollBack $rollBack -updateDataOnly $updateDataOnly -scriptMapLokaal $scriptMapLokaal -buildDrop $buildDrop -dataPadNetwerk $dataPadNetwerk
if (-not $return) {
    $stopWatch.Stop()
    Read-Host -Prompt "`nHet script is beëindigd. Toets Enter om af te sluiten"
    exit
}

$return = .\Subscripts\2_afleidenParameters.ps1 -versie $versie -versieSoort $versieSoort -dataSet $dataSet -rollBack $rollBack -updateDataOnly $updateDataOnly -scriptMapLokaal $scriptMapLokaal -buildDrop $buildDrop -dataPadNetwerk $dataPadNetwerk -versieNieuwstLokaal $versieNieuwstLokaal
if (-not $return) {
    $stopWatch.Stop()
    Read-Host -Prompt "`nHet script is beëindigd. Toets Enter om af te sluiten"
    exit
} else {
    if (!$versieSoort) {
        $versieSoort = $return[0]
    }
    $buildMapNetwerk = $return[1]
    $buildPadNetwerk = $return[2]
}

.\Subscripts\3_kopierenBuild.ps1 -versie $versie -versieSoort $versieSoort -updateDataOnly $updateDataOnly -scriptMapLokaal $scriptMapLokaal -buildMapNetwerk $buildMapNetwerk -buildPadNetwerk $buildPadNetwerk

if ($rollBack) {
    .\Subscripts\4_verwijderInstallaties.ps1 -versie $versie -versieSoort $versieSoort -rollBack $rollBack
}

if (-not $updateDataOnly -or !$updateDataOnly) {
    .\Subscripts\5_installerenBuild.ps1 -versie $versie -versieSoort $versieSoort -scriptMapLokaal $scriptMapLokaal -buildMapNetwerk $buildMapNetwerk
}

.\Subscripts\6_updateData.ps1 -versie $versie -versieSoort $versieSoort -dataSet $dataSet -scriptMapLokaal $scriptMapLokaal -dataPadNetwerk $dataPadNetwerk -buildMapNetwerk $buildMapNetwerk

if (-not $updateDataOnly -or !$updateDataOnly) {
    .\Subscripts\7_installerenNxtClient.ps1 -versieSoort $versieSoort -scriptMapLokaal $scriptMapLokaal
}

$stopWatch.Stop()
$aantalSeconden = $stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds
Read-Host -Prompt "`nScript voltooid in $aantalSeconden seconden. Toets Enter om af te sluiten"
```

Comment: "the main script always exits" perhaps because PowerShell reaches the last statement in the script? You haven't shown anything indicating that the script should keep running forever... Perhaps you could post the whole script?

Comment: @PhilipStuij, code in comments does not work well. Please edit the question to add it as text and formatted as code like you did with the initial code.

Comment: I edited the question with the response I gave @MathiasR.Jessen but I celebrated a bit too soon there.

To address the matter that Mathias raised, I've included the entire main script in the original question.

Comment: To which I should add that when the script exited (with the original solution), it did so with the write host-message. So if I'm understanding @MathiasR.Jessen correctly, it is not a matter of the script not having to keep running.

Comment: That makes sense but unfortunately, it gets me the same result: the main scripts never exits. I do see the error message that's in the if statement of the sub script so it should return $false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to give up but had a light bulb moment and tried the below succesfully.

Subscripts simply go like this:

```
$testSomething = Test-Path $something
if (-not $testSomething) {
    write-host 'error message'
    exit
}
```

Only returning something if they make it to the end:

```
$result = 'OK'
return $result
```

I was dismayed when the following didn't work in the main script:

```
if ($return -ne 'OK') {
    Read-Host -Prompt 'Press Enter to exit'
    exit
}
```

But found out that the return value here is actually $true (not sure why) so finally got it to work like this:

```
if (-not $return) {
    Read-Host -Prompt 'Press Enter to exit'
    exit
}
```

Comment: As I have explained in my answer your approach to just calling `-not $variable` is a bad idea - especially if you don't know what typ `$variable` will be. Please for the love of it make it an explicit check! Negating a value of unkown type will lead to unexpected results - as shown by your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your subscript would never reach its exit statement. Your main script only check for `-not $return`. There are quiet some values that would evaluate as true in this case.

[`-not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.1) will try to negate the value. Negating `$null`, which is going to be the return value of your script unless your test fails, will be `$true` so your script will exit.

Rather than using the `-not` make it explicit and actually do what you suggested in your initial statement - check for the string exit.

```
$x = $null
if(-not $x){Write-Output "X is not false"}
```

Comment: I think I understand your problem with my second attempt but that brings me back to my first attempt. I'm not sure what you're actually suggesting other than what I've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion exit closes the session.

If you just want to leave the sub-function you can just as well use return.
Just plain "Return" return would return nothing but return 'Exit' would feed the $return variable in the main script with the string "Exit".

Return is the way to leave a function either empty or loaded as I call it.
When loaded you can further the process the load from the main script.

If you use a try{}catch{} you can do something like this:

```
Try{
    "some code to test"
}
Catch {Return $error[0]}
Return "success"
```

Any failure but be catched by the catch the return makes you leave the function. Feeding the $Result variable in the main script with whatever is in $Error[0] after which the next statement in the main script is processed.

Maybe [This link](https://jorgecandeias.github.io/2014/11/27/the-difference-between-break-return-and-exit-in-powershell/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20the%20keywords%20Exit%2C,to%20the%20statement%20immediately%20after%20the%20function%20call.) will help.

Let me make sure that this is what you are trying to do:

```
Function test2 {
Try {1/0}
Catch {Return $error[0].exception.gettype().fullname}
Return 'OK'
}

function test1 {
$result = test2
$result
}
```

PS E:\Test> test1

Results in:

System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException

When I change function2 tot this:

```
Function test2 {
Try {$test = 1/1}
Catch {Return $error[0].exception.gettype().fullname}
Return 'OK'
}
```

$Return results in 'OK'

Comment: I've considered your answer and the information in the link and tried feeding a result variable with either 'stop' or 'OK' but neither using "if ($return -eq 'stop'), nor if ($return -ne 'OK') gives the desired result. Am I missing the point?

Worth mentioning is that I don't use functions.

I think I'll just forgo using sub scripts and lump 'em all together but it bugs me to no end that I can't get this to work.

Comment: I have added some explanatory code. Please have a look at it and let me know if this is what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: This looks like it should work but in the meantime I found a solution that fits better in my case and also does the trick. I'll keep the try and catch method in mind, though, for fure reference. Thank you.